# Seaborn heatmap colors - same colors for the magnitude of values

Tags: python, seaborn

I have values of a matrix going from +1 to -1 and I would like the same color for +1 and -1. Is there a way to do this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

# Load the example flights dataset and convert to long-form
flights_long = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights_long.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

# Draw a heatmap with the numeric values in each cell
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
mv1 = np.mean(flights.mean());
sns.heatmap(flights- mv1, annot=True)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use seaborn's [`diverging_palette()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.diverging_palette.html) to generate such a cmap by passing the same hue value for the negative and positive end of the cmap.

```
data = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(10,10))
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(240,240, as_cmap=True)
sns.heatmap(data, cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't simply `sns.heatmap(np.abs(data))` be enough?

Comment: I guess, but then the colorbar would only go down to zero, and that could be confusing to a reader of the plot.